# Brownie.panel component in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp

I have installed the browine plugin in cake php. but it is showing problem. Please suggest.

> Missing Component Error: Brownie.panelComponent could not be found.
>   Error: Create the class panelComponent below in file:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\newcakefood\app\Plugin\Brownie\Controller\Component\panelComponent.php

```
<?php
class panelComponent extends Component {

}
```

> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create
>   app\View\Errors\missing_component.ctp Stack Trace
>   CORE\Cake\Controller\ComponentCollection.php line 53 →
>   ComponentCollection->load(string, array)
>   CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php line 639 →
>   ComponentCollection->init(PagesController)
>   CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php line 183 →
>   Controller->constructClasses() CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php line
>   162 → Dispatcher->_invoke(PagesController, CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
>   APP\webroot\index.php line 111 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest,
>   CakeResponse)

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message: panelComponent. Class and file names are case sensitive, it should be an upper cased P, Panel. Check your component array where you load it.

Comment: That's the right cause but class names (i.e. php) [are not case sensitive](http://codepad.viper-7.com/lNZQze).

Comment: True but they become basically case sensitive when loaded through autoloaders because the autoloader tries to map them to a file name by convention.

Comment: I don't disagree (obviously) but this statement is factually wrong: `Class [names] are case sensitive`